# accessing remote services functions

Tags: java, android, service

i ran into a problem with remote services. after i started and bound my service, i want/need to access it's functionality. this works just fine if i work with buttons and onclick-controllers just as in http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteServiceBinding.html

but actually, i need to access the services functions DIRECTLY after binding the service, like:

Intent intent = new Intent(IwlService.class.getName());
bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

String.valueOf(wlService.getDataFromService()); // this will CRASH the app!!!

if i access the service function "getDataFromService()" in an onClickListener, it works perfectly.

how do i access the services functions directly after binding/starting the service?

Answer (score 1):

> but actually, i need to access the
>   services functions DIRECTLY after
>   binding the service, like:

That is not possible. The service may need to start up, for example. In the case of a remote service, that will take a few hundred milliseconds.

> how do i access the services functions
>   directly after binding/starting the
>   service?

You don't. You rewrite your code to access your service starting with the `onServiceConnected()` method in your `ServiceConnection` object. Any time before that and your service is not ready.